# how to use redis in windows 10 from .msi installer

Tags: windows, redis

I have a question about how to run Redis in Windows 10. What I have done is :
I have installed Redis using `.msi` and my Redis is running in the services. But when I run `redis-cli` command in CMD, I get an error like this :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>redis-cli
'redis-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I fix this problem and how to run Redis in Windows locally? Do I have to add the Redis to an environment or something?

Comment: I suggest you check out Memurai. The Redis project you are using has been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Do the first option only if you have not shutdown your computer and not closed you terminal after installation

1. Close your terminal open again and try running redis-cli, if that doesn't works then do below,
2. Uninstall and Reinstall again, while reinstalling make sure that you check **"Add the redis installation folder to the PATH environment variable"**